# Putting flipped plates together as close as possible

Tags: building, snot, connections

I have two plates that I would like to connect together and collapse with the studs facing out like in the image below. I need the two plates to sit as close together as possible. But I'd like them to open up fully so all the studs face the same direction as well.

I came up with an idea with horizontal clips and a bar (shown in image). Or maybe using a hinge plate, but then I need to reverse the studs which takes some space.

[image]

Any idea how to do it as thin as possible?

[image]
[image]

Comment: You mean that it can expand and close in between?

Comment: Yeah I've added two more images showing the hinge action I'd like, but just like it to be as close as possible when closed.

Comment: Huh, I recall knowing a few SNOT hacks for this, I'll see if I can recover them. Only thing is that they don't allow to expand the space in between.

Comment: Are third party bricks allowed? I know a special brick from a clone-brand that might suit your needs.

Comment: I'd appreciate it, thanks.

Comment: I'd obviously prefer Lego only, but if it's a much better solution I'd be open to it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a bit of a challenge with a geometry. LEGO doesn't produce much symmetrical hinges, otherwise they would be out of system. I could think of the following one piece you could achieve a close result - [Hinge Plate 2 x 4 with Pin Hole and 3 Holes - Top](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=98286#T=C). It comes in White color as well, so you could incorporate in your layer of white plates.

[image]

Here's a solution using this part. Only downside - it has a little gap.

[image][image]

Comment: I think I missed this hinge plate where the connection is offset. I think this may be as thin as possible. Going to try this out. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

this way it can open and close

[image]

[image]

Blue = [4276 Hinge Plate 1 x 2 with 2 Fingers](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4276&name=Hinge%20Plate%201%20x%202%20with%202%20Fingers&category=%5BHinge%5D#T=C)

Yellow = [4275 Hinge Plate 1 x 2 with 3 Fingers](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4275&name=Hinge%20Plate%201%20x%202%20with%203%20Fingers&category=%5BHinge%5D#T=C)

LightBlue = Plate 2 x 4

White = Plate 2 x 2

Pink = Plate 1 x 4

Light Bluish Gray = Plate 1 x 3

Yellowish Green = Plate 1 x 2

Red = Tile 2 x 2

Green = Tile 1 x 4

Comment: Really cool design, unless I'm not understanding your design correctly, I'm looking to open and close fully like my 2nd and 3rd images. Your design closes as tight as possible which I love, but the light blue piece I think would get in the way when open or closed.

Comment: @bsf10 I believe that the "fully opened" state would be a T shape, with the blue part pointing down (or up).  You may be able to use [Hinge Plate 1 x 2 with 3 Fingers On Side](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2452&name=Hinge%20Plate%201%20x%202%20with%203%20Fingers%20On%20Side&category=%5BHinge%5D#T=C) to make it 1 stud deep instead of 2

Comment: Yeah I agree, I love how tight it is but the T shape unfortunately won't fit.

Comment: Here is another example why they should re-introduce those lovely 4275/4276 hinge plates.

Answer (score 3):

This is one method using [levers](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4593#T=C)

[image]

via [Swooshable](https://swooshable.com/snot/2-or-more-levers-and-plates)

Comment: The problem here is that the OP needs it to be a such a way that you can easily open up the inside, he already gave one of his own examples. But this is still good to know. You can also use [bucket handles](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=95344&name=Container,%20Bucket%201%20x%201%20x%201%20Handle%20/%20Scooter%20Stand%20&category=%5BContainer%5D#T=C) and minifig hands instead if you want.

Comment: Might be a decent solution with the standard hinge plate? Not exactly an approved Lego design but if it works....?

Comment: @bsf10 normally they would create noticeable space in between, and you would likely need to add SNOT hacks, which would create even more space in between.